# Dynamic Links and jQuery Lightbox issue : Loading image in lightbox...completely stumped!

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have a function that dynamically creates links for a photo gallery. The function also produces a larger image as a background image of a div when and thumbnail is clicked on. What I want to do is have a third event, where if the user clicks the enlarged image in the div, the jQuery Fancybox loads an even bigger version of the image being displayed in the div. The problem is that the link for the anchor tag I'm using is created dynamically, and I know that Fancybox parses the HTML when the DOM is ready...unfortunately my function changes the DOM by appending the anchor tag for the full sized image. The help I need is using the Fancybox's options to specify the href attribute for the plugin. I'm sorry that was so long-winded...here's the code.

jQuery:

```
function gallery(picid, picnum){
var ext = 'jpg';
var fullSize = 'imgs/'+picid+'_full.'+ext;
$('#photolarge').css("background", 'url(imgs/'+picid+'_large.'+ext+') no-repeat');
$('#photolarge a').attr(
    {   href: fullSize
        //rel: 'lightbox',  
    }
    );

$("#lightboxlink").click(function(){
    $('#lightboxlink').fancybox({
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 'auto',
        'height' : 'auto',
        'href' : fullSize
        });


    });




return false;
```

}

HTML Snippet

```
<div id="photolarge">
   <a id="lightboxlink" href="#"></a>
</div>
        <div id="phototable">
            <ul id="photorow1">
                <li><a onclick="gallery('bigsun',1)"><img id="sun" src="imgs/bigsun.jpg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Subsequent CSS:

```
#photolarge {
width: 590px;
height: 400px;
margin-left: 7px;
border: 2px solid;
background: none;}

#phototable {
width: 590px;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid;
margin: 10px 0 0 7px;}

#phototable img {
cursor: pointer;}

#phototable ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline;}

#phototable li {
padding-left: 10px;}

#lightboxlink {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for the event handler, and [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to immediately open the lightbox, like this:

```
$("#lightboxlink").live('click', function(e){
    $(this).filter(':not(.fb)').fancybox({
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 'auto',
        'height' : 'auto',
        'href' : fullSize
     }).addClass('fb');
     $(this).triggerHandler('click');
     e.preventDefault(); //prevent opening in new window
});
```

This runs `.fancybox()` on the link, but only if we haven't *already* run it, which we're tracking with a `.fb` class addition.  Whether it's a new or fresh bind, we need to trigger the `click` handler, which is what `fancybox` listens to in order to open.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried .live().

Thank you, but I'm still getting the problem where the link created loads the image in a new window.

Comment: @Christian - oh woops, you need a prevent default, one moment

Comment: @Christian - I updated for this, though fancybox *should* be taking care of it already.

Comment: @Nick Hmmm...the image is still loading in a new window. Your code makes sense, which is even more strange (although I'm still amateurish at javascript). I must have some sore of mistake in another part of my documents.

Comment: @Christian - Any error in your console? A JavaScript error means the default behavior takes over...which is what you're seeing it sounds like.

Comment: @Nick There are no errors in my console..I've really nitpicked all parts of my code, including the HTML. I can't imagine what the problem could be, even after using .live()

Comment: @Christian - Can you update your question to include the HTML containing the `#lightboxlink`?, second pair of eyes may help.

Comment: @Nick I updated and added a bit more of the HTML around it. Another set of eyes may be just what this needs.

Comment: @Christian - Which part of that is getting replaced on the fly?

Comment: @Nick - The image link that #lightboxlink points to is created on the fly as well as the actual href attribute. (if that answers your question /: )

Comment: @Nick - I slept on it and came back this morning and read over the code. I found a silly mistake with my placing of the preventDefault that you suggested. Everything works great now, thanks so much for your help!