# Lightbox not working after new images load

Tags: jquery, image, lightbox

Initialize lightbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/slimbox2.js"></script>
```

I have static images on page:

```
<a class="itogdetimg" href="" rel="lightbox" title="">
    <img width="83px" src="/img.png" border="0"/>
</a>
```

And i have link with `id="knav1"` on click this load new images with jquery script:

```
$("#knav1").click(function(){
        $("#navldesc").load('/api.php?nvl=y&komplektn=Комплит2');
});
```

Links type is the same as above, but lightbox with them no longer works. I think this is because of was originally do not have them on page. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: the part where you initialize lightbox is missing in you provided code. but likely the problem is because jquery selectors like `$("[rel='lightbox']").lightbox()` only apply to the elements that are in the dom at the time you call selector. so you need to apply lightbox to the new added element, with a success callback for load (but how to do correctly depends on the lightbox plugin you use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For slimbox2 this should work:

```
$("#knav1").click(function(){
        $("#navldesc").load('/api.php?nvl=y&komplektn=Комплит2',function() {
             $("#navldesc").find("[rel='lightbox']").slimbox(/*if you have custom options place them here*/);
        });
});
```

As mention my initial comment, the problem is that slimbox2 does not care about images that where added by ajax. so you need to apply `slimbox` to the newly added images yourself.

But as far as i can see slimbox2 was not updated for a long time, so it could happen that it is not compatible with newer versions of jquery. i would recommend that you should think of an alternative. i have an own ui framework so i can really give a good recommandation about what library is better. (these look like they are up to date: [fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) [lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/))

Comment: fancybox also sucks with dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

There is more then one post in the subject...

[Dynamic Links and jQuery Lightbox issue : Loading image in lightbox...completely stumped!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420056/dynamic-links-and-jquery-lightbox-issue-loading-image-in-lightbox-completely?rq=1)

[Lightbox Not Working on AJAX Load Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652726/lightbox-not-working-on-ajax-load-parts?rq=1)

[activate lightbox on dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597511/activate-lightbox-on-dynamically-added-content)

The answer is simple

**Change to:**

```
$("selector").live('click', function (){
      $(this).lightBox();
});
```

**Alt** *(Depending on what Jquery Version you're using 1.7+)*

```
$("selector").on('click', function (){
      $(this).lightBox();
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated since 1.7 that should be mentioned.

Comment: @t.niese there updated with an alternative for later versions =)

Comment: but not correctly ;) the equivalent to `$("#knav1").live('click', ...` is `$(document).on('click', '#knav1', ...` but anyway i don't think that `#knav1` is replaced by another link with the same id, the problem is more that the click handler for the lightbox are not attached.

Answer (score -1):

You can use live() method of jquery to make all new elements appearing on page working.
You have to alter you current lightbox function to use live();
Possible solution is something about this:

```
$("a.itogdetimg").live("click", function(){ $(this).lightbox(); });
```